# Como guardar un valor de DateTimePicker de C# en un campo DateTime de MySQL

Tags: mysql, poo, visual

Tengo un datetimepicker en un windows forms en C# y quiero registrar una fecha utilizando lo que es el control datetimepicker y guardarlo en el fecha que es tipo "date" en MySql

```
        public void setAdd(string nombre, string animal, string raza, DateTime fecha, string dueño, string tipo_c, string desc_c, string foto)
    {
        cn.Insert("INSERT INTO prueba_cons(nombre, Animal, Raza, Fecha, duenho, Tipo_Consulta, Desc_consulta, foto) values('" + nombre + "', '" + animal + "','" + raza + "'," + fecha + ",'"+ dueño + "','" + tipo_c + "','" + desc_c + "','" + foto + "')");
    }
```

Y este sería el botón para agregar, no sé que me falta o que debo arreglar, se los agradezco mucho

```
            //string Date = dtpDate.Value.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
            db.setAdd(txtName.Text, cmbAnimal.Text, txtRace.Text, dtpDate.Value, txtowner.Text, cmbType.Text, rtxObs.Text, txtRoute.Text);
            MessageBox.Show("Registro guardado correctamente.", "Guardado", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Comment: Cual es el error

Answer (score 0):

depende del formato de fecha que acepta MySQL...el mas común es yyyy-MM-dd

```
public void setAdd(string nombre, string animal, string raza, DateTime fecha, string dueño, string tipo_c, string desc_c, string foto)
    {
        cn.Insert("INSERT INTO prueba_cons(nombre, Animal, Raza, Fecha, duenho, Tipo_Consulta, Desc_consulta, foto) values('" + nombre + "', '" + animal + "','" + raza + "','" + fecha.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "','"+ dueño + "','" + tipo_c + "','" + desc_c + "','" + foto + "')");
    }
```

Comment: +1, me ha servido mucho, tengo otra duda, habrá forma de evitar que el dato se guarde con la hora, por ejemplo pongo la fecha y se guarda así: 2020-11-23 00:00:00

Comment: Claro, es cuestion de formato. En vez de fecha.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), seria fecha.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")